# A metric space from closed sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

From Mendelson's *Introduction to Topology*:

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. ... [Then] $X$ is open.

But consider the closed interval $[a,b]$ over the real numbers.  Presumably there is a distance function $d$ such that $([a,b],d)$ is a metric space.  But $[a,b]$ is not an open set.  What, then, have I missed?

---

To expand upon my question, here is my rough counterproof.

An open set is a neighborhood of each of its points.  Consider the metric space $(X,d)$, with $X = [a,b]$ and $d(x,y) = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.  If $X$ is open, then $X$ must be a neighborhood of $a$, which means there must be an open ball $B(a;\delta)\subset X$ for some $\delta > 0$.  Yet if $\delta > 0$, then there is some $c \in B(a;\delta)$ such that $c < a$.  Therefore $c \notin X$; a contradiction.

What is the flaw in my logic here?

Comment: $[a,b]$ is open in itself. Any metric space is its own universe. By definition, any open ball is contained in the universe.

Comment: $[a,b]$ is not open in $\mathbb R$, but it _is_ open in $[a,b]$ itself.

Comment: Think about this; $R$ is not open in $R^2$, but it is open in $R$. open/closed property is very dependent on the underlying space. 

(anyway how can I write the real number set R? mathds doesnt work... $\mathds{R}$)

Comment: Thanks all for your comments - I have expanded my question to clarify this.  @dust05: \mathbb{R}

Comment: I think the natural definition of the open ball in $X$ is defined as $B(x;\delta)\cap X$ in this case.

Comment: @Doubt: `\mathbb R`. No need for braces when the argument to `\mathbb` is a single character (but you do need a space as there is no `\mathbbR`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any metric space is a topological space and the space itself is always open with respect to its topology. It may fail to be open with respect to the topology of some *other* topological space it is a subspace of. Here, no such super-space is mentioned.

Or reread the definiion of open set exactly: If $(X,d)$ is a metric space, then for $x\in X$ and $r\in \mathbb R_{>0}$ the set $B_r(x):=\{\,y\color{red}{\in X}\mid d(x,y)<r\,\}$ is called open $r$-ball around $x$ and $U\subseteq X$ is called open iff for each $x\in U$, there exists some $r>0$ with $B_r(x)\subseteq U$. For $X=[0,1]$ and the usual metric note that these definition make e.g. $B_{\frac12}(\frac13)=[0,\frac56)$ an open set.